# Advance Query with Join

Tags: sql, join, union, unique

I'm trying to convert a product table that contains all the detail of the product into separate tables in SQL.   I've got everything done except  for duplicated descriptor details.

The problem I am having all the products have size/color/style/other  that many other products contain.   I want to only have one size or color descriptor for all the items and reuse the "ID" for all the product which I believe is a  Parent key to the Product ID which is a ...Foreign Key.  The only problem is that every descriptor would have multiple Foreign Keys assigned to it.  So I was thinking on the fly just have it skip figuring out a Foreign Parent key for each descriptor and just check to see if that descriptor exist and if it does use its Key for the descriptor.

Data Table

```
PI  Colo   Sz   OTHER


1        |   Blue  |  5  |    Vintage

2        |   Blue  |  6   |   Vintage

3        |   Blac  | 5   |   Simple

4        |   Blac |  6   |   Simple
```

===================================

Its destination table is this

===================================

```
DI Description

1       |   Blue

2       |   Blac

3       |   5

4       |   6

6       |   Vintage

7       |  Simple
```

=============================

Select Data.Table

Unique.Data.Table.Colo

Unique.Data.Table.Sz

Unique.Data.Table.Other

=======================================

Then the dual part of the questions after we create all the descriptors how to do a new query and assign the product ID to the descriptors.

PI| DI

1 | 1

1 | 3

1 | 4

2 | 1

2 | 3

2 | 4

By figuring out how to do this I should be able to duplicate this pattern for all 300 + columns in the product.   Some of these fields are 60+ characters large so its going to save a ton of space.

Do I use a Array?

Comment: So you're trying to get all unique values of the `Colo` field into a separate `Colo` table, and same for `Sz` and `Other`... they too have their own tables right? And the primary keys are auto-incrementing correct?

Comment: Yea, that is correct.   But they all go into the same table again called attributes or descriptions and the primary keys will auto-increment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, if I understand you correctly, you want all unique attributes converted from columns into rows in a single table (`detailstable`) that has an id and a description field:

Assuming the schema:

```
datatable
------------------
PI [PK]
Colo
Sz
OTHER

detailstable
------------------
DI [PK]
Description
```

You can first get all of the unique attributes into its own table with:

```
INSERT INTO detailstable (Description)
SELECT 
    a.description
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT Colo AS description
        FROM datatable

        UNION

        SELECT DISTINCT Sz AS description
        FROM datatable

        UNION

        SELECT DISTINCT OTHER AS description
        FROM datatable
    ) a
```

Then to link up the `datatable` to the `detailstable`, I'm assuming you have a cross-reference table defined like:

```
datadetails
------------------
PI [PK]
DI [PK]
```

You can then do:

```
INSERT INTO datadetails (PI, DI)
SELECT
    a.PI
    b.DI
FROM
    datatable a
INNER JOIN
    detailstable b ON b.Description IN (a.Colo, a.Sz, a.OTHER)
```

Comment: I think that is it, Union was they key, thank you!  Now I can Begin the 300+ column union../shiver

Answer (score 0):

I reckon you want to split description table for different categories, like - colorDescription, sizeDescription etc.

If that is not practical then I would recommend having an extra column showing an category attribute:

```
DI Description  Category

1 | Blue       | Color

2 | Blac       | Color

3 | 5          | Size

4 | 6          | Size

6 | Vintage    | Other

7 | Simple     | Other
```

And then have primary key in this table as combination of ID and Category column.

This will have less chances for injecting any data errors. It will be also easy to track that down.

Comment: Yea, I did forget about that.  We would have a extra column (all the attributes are being changed to ID's I believe)